# Why Is My Closure working when I use the addEventListener method, but not with the onclick HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, html, functional-programming, frontend, closures

I try to get a button only to be clicked once.

```
var user, sales, data;

function getBill(user, sales, data) {
    window.alert("Here is your bill.");
    //do the billing process
}

const once = fn => {
    let finished = false;
    return (...args) => {
        if (!finished) {
            finished = true;
            fn(...args);
        }
    };
};
```

When I use this HTML with the onclick. The button will alert every time I click the button, because it goes into once and sets "finished" back to false.

```
<button id="billButton" onclick="once(getBill)(user,sales,data)">Pay Order</button>
```

However, removing the onclick attribute and using the method of "addEventListener" makes this button being clickable only one time.

```
document.getElementById("billButton").addEventListener('click' ,once(getBill)(user, sales, data));
```

How does it come and how can I use the "onclick" attribute? I know attribute listeners are bad practice, but that is not the term. It should work both ways properly.

What am I missing?

Comment: The addEventListener will attach `undefined` to the `click` event and will run the function on the page load itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's look how the `onclick` attribute in `HTML` works:

1. It will just store the function calling statement in plain text.
2. When you click on the element it checks if there is anything in `onclick` attribute.
3. If there is anything in `onclick` attribute, it will just simply execute it with `eval`.

Coming back to your code, whenever you click on the button it will always show the alert because it calls a new function every time, it doesn't store the function returned from the `once`.

```js
var user, sales, data;

function getBill(user, sales, data) {
  window.alert("Here is your bill.");
}

const once = fn => {
  let finished = false;
  return (...args) => {
    if (!finished) {
      finished = true;
      fn(...args);
    }
  };
};
```

```html
<button id="billButton" onclick="once(getBill)(user,sales,data)">Pay Order</button>
```

Now, let's look at how the `eventListener` works:

1. EventListeners bind the function reference to the events.
2. So whenever that particular event emits, it invokes the function bound to it.

Again, coming back to your code, you are not binding the function to the `eventListener` you are binding the return value of the function to the event which in this case is `undefined`.

The correct way to bind the response of high order function is, using `bind`, yes:

```js
document.getElementById("billButton").addEventListener('click' ,once(getBill).bind(this, user, sales, data));
```

```js
var user, sales, data;

function getBill(user, sales, data) {
  window.alert("Here is your bill.");
}

const once = fn => {
  let finished = false;
  return (...args) => {
    if (!finished) {
      finished = true;
      fn(...args);
    }
  };
};

document.getElementById("billButton").addEventListener('click', once(getBill).bind(this, user, sales, data));
```

```html
<button id="billButton">Pay Order</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, man. I was recreating the example from the Book Mastering Javascript Functional Programming, but the author left out these details...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use correctly the `addEventListener`, because you didn't add event.
Another suggestion is do what i did, so click on button start your function then replace old button with new one without `EventListener` like:

```js
const user = 'simon',
  sales = '1',
  data = 'today',
  button = document.getElementById("billButton");

function getBill(user, sales, data) {
  //tips add load here
  window.alert("Here is your bill."); 
  //on finish stop loader
}

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  getBill(user, sales, data);
  let buttonClone = button.cloneNode(true); // create clone html (don't clone the event)
  button.parentNode.replaceChild(buttonClone, button); // replace it
  buttonClone.disabled = true; //disable button
});
```

```html
<button id="billButton">Pay Order</button>
```

Comment: I corrected my code. I missed the 'onclick' type. But anyways. It should work both ways properly. This is a technique of using closures and higher-order functions. I want to stick to it with no dependencies on DOM Elements.